# Unexpected PhpMyAdmin login screen after installing wamp server

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I've installed wamp server in my system. Everything went fine.After installation when I clicked at phpmyadmin this login portal pops up.[I don't know what is the username or password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiyoL.png)

How I'm supposed to login without username and password.

Comment: try with username = "root" without password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay its quite easy.

put 
username = "root"
password = " "(blank)

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

username root password root try this or username root with blank password

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `username` of `root` and password with nothing.
If you wish to change your `root` password take a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118772/how-to-change-root-password-for-mysql-and-phpmyadmin) and it will explain all the ways that you can.

Hope this helps!